# Tymon JWT user_not_found - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1, jwt

I am building an api for a mobile app, and I am using JWT to authenticate users. I am trying to implement it in Laravel 5.1.

I keep getting the error: `{"error":"user_not_found"}` whenever I use the token that was given to me by the authenticate method.

My process:

1. Authenticate the user using `Auth::attempt($credentials)`
2. Get the user from the db using `$user = User::where('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)->first();`
3. Set the Token for the user using

   ```
   $token = "";
   try {
       // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
       if (! $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user)) {
           return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
       }
   } catch (JWTException $e) {
           // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
           return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
   }
   ```

It is returning a token using this method:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOm51bGwsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3BlZGxyLmRldlwvYXBpXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTQ0OTk2NDQ2NywiZXhwIjoxNDQ5OTY4MDY3LCJuYmYiOjE0NDk5NjQ0NjcsImp0aSI6IjJlMDMyMjA5MjMyZWM1MDVlY2I3YzE4ODFjNDk1MzFmIn0.tbO_fv4WDQ6WgiHtyYJAq2rjnOtaYPq85VO2ja2YVzw
```

But when trying to authenticate the user using the token, it throws the error `{"error":"user_not_found"}`.

My routes.php:

```
Route::any('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'APIController@postLogin']);
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function()   {
    Route::any('/users', ['as' => 'users', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getUsers']);
});
```

If I take the middleware group out, I can access the `/users` route. 
I think it is happening somewhere in the `GetUserFromToken` class in the `Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware` namespace as that is the only place that lists the error `user_not_found`.

My database uses `user_id`, not just `id` as primary keys, could this be the issue?

Comment: you're already answered in your question

Comment: @PeteHouston check my answer from 2 hours ago. I managed to sort it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I got it.

I went into the `config/jwt.php` file that was created when publishing the `JWTAuthServiceProvider` and then I changed the `identifier` to the primary key of my Users table (as the `user` setting is set to `App\User`, my primary key is `user_id` in the User model).

```
'identifier' => 'user_id' // somewhere around line 79
```

And it worked.

Comment: Pretty lame :D Could have found that be ready the manual more closely, instead of SOl!!!  https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need a login route, that creates a session first. Then get the user.

```
Route::post('sessions/create', ['uses' => 'Auth\JwtAuthController@authenticate']);
Route::get('sessions/user', ['uses' => 'Auth\JwtAuthController@getAuthenticatedUser']);
```

Try the following code in your controller:

```
/**
 * Authenticate by credentials
 */
public function authenticate()
{

    $credentials = request()->only('email', 'password');

    try {

        if ( !$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials) ) {
            return $this->error('invalid-credentials', 401);
        }

    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return $this->error('could-not-create-token', 500);
    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'));

}


/**
 * Get the user by jwt token, or return an error
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{

    try {

        if ( !$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate() ) {
            return $this->error('user-not-found', 204);
        }

    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return $this->error('token-expired', 401);

    } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return $this->error('token-invalid', 401);

    } catch (JWTException $e) {

        return $this->error('token-absent', 400);

    }

    // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim
    return response()->json(compact('user'));
}


/**
 * Error formatter
 *
 * @param  string  $message
 * @param  integer $statuscode
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
private function error($message, $statuscode = 401)
{
    return response()->json(['error' => $message], $statuscode);
}
```

Comment: But it is giving me the token in the first request

Comment: 1). First you post your login details to /sessions/create. 2). When the token get's back to you..then the user has valid credentials. This means you can then use the token for all further authorization things.

Comment: I am doing that, I am getting the token back, I have valid credentials, but the token does not work after that.

Comment: You need to set a Request header with the token. Authorization:Bearer token

Answer (score 0):

## **Solution...**

If your code is correct, then also if your getting output:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_credentials"
}
```

## **Just Follow this Steps:---------------**

### **first step check:**

`dd($request->only('email', 'password'));` **or** `dd($credentials);`
 // output should be like this..

```
array:2 [
  "email" => "myemail@myemail.com"
  "password" => "test123"
]
```

### **second step check:**

```
 dd($token);
```

// output should be: false

### **Third step check:**

1)   Inside of `app/Http/Kernel.php` make sure `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` is commented out.
  2)  Inside `config/jwt.php` make sure you have the identifier set to the primary key of your Users table.

`'identifier' => 'userid'` // default is set to 'id'

### **Last Step Goto: App\Config\auth.php**

On line number: 70 Change Model Location where your saved model(User)

for example: `App\Model\Myuser\User`

**and**

On line number: 71 Change Table Name to what you have set in your model(User)

for example: `protected $table = 'my_user';`

```
 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Myuser\User::class,
            'table' => 'my_user'
        ],
```

### It may help you....

Answer (score -1):

Try it: In User model write the single line: protected `$primaryKey = 'user_id'`;

Example:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'my_user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
}
```