# Laravel JWT Auth Returning False

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, dingo-api

I have followed the tutorial below but when I get the current user it always returns false.  I am able to sign in and get my token in postman.  I then create the url and hit send.  However the following function always returns false.

```
$currentUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
dd(currentUser)
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-api-only-jwt-powered-laravel-app/

Update
When I run the below code I get the token value.

```
$token = JWTAuth::getToken();
JWTAuth::setToken($token);
```

The code fails at the following point

```
if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
    return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
}
```

Comment: you passed generated token with your request? https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/1455663699postman_other_test.png

Comment: that is correct like http://localhost:8080/test?token=123456.  Using the token I was provided at login.

Comment: I did use an account that I signed up with via a form as apposed to the api.  But still got the token when I logged in.

Comment: Yes, please see https://cask.scotch.io/2015/06/angular-laravel-auth-5-1.png

Comment: please read document. https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer that solved my problem.  I was using user_id as opposed to id.  I changed this in the jwt config file.

[Tymon JWT user_not_found - Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246464/tymon-jwt-user-not-found-laravel-5-1/34246991#34246991)

More on this below

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/155